# How to center headers and add lines in all pages using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr

I added a header in all my pages using the package `fancyhdr`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=0cm, outer=3cm, inner=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead[L]{ \leftmark}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\normalsize\bfseries\thepage}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\denumero}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\iznumero}]
  {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{% 
\chaptername}\ \thechapter.%
\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{asd}
\lipsum
asasasd

\chapter{asd2}
\lipsum

\chapter{asd3}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However I don't understand why I don't have header lines in all the pages, it only appears in the first page of every chapter. I used

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

But it doesn't change

On the other hand I want to center the header, I tried using

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

but it doesn't center the header.

How can I solve this? I wrote in the code all the packages I'm using in case the problem is there.

Comment: If you're using `memoir`, there's no need to use the `fancyhdr` package. The [`memoir`](http://wbc.upm.edu.my/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) user manual  (Sect 7.3) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading `fancyhdr` you should set facystyle by `\pagestyle{fancy}` command to make latex using this page style.

As you can see in the `fancyhdr` manual, `\fancyhead` macro has several selectors, in this case `R` means right field; p7 of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `fancyhdr` package with `memoir` which has its own set of commands for headers. In particular for your case `memoir` provides several kinds of headers that only apply in particular cases. For example there is a general header style for regular text pages but there is a specific header style that only applies to the first page of chapters. As Troy said, in effect; Read the manual.